Drupal Core Upgrade From 9.5 to 10 Blockers
I am just few step behind upgrading drupal core from 9.5 to 10. I have upgraded all contributed module and fixed patched modules which i can. But below modules are blocker for me.

CiviCRM Entity 8.x-3.5
CSV Serialization 3.0.1
Sparkpost email 8.x-2.2



Above modules do not have any release which support 9 and 10. So i can not upgrade drupal core because of these modules dependencies with 9.5. Neither i can upgrade above modules as there release only support drupal core 10.
Please help me guys.
I tried to run below code
composer require 'drupal/sparkpost:^3.0@alpha' 'drupal/csv_serialization:^4.0' 'drupal/civicrm_entity:^4.0@beta' drupal/core-recommended:10.1.8 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:10.1.8 drupal/core-project-message:10.1.8 --update-with-all-dependencies

Response:
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 10.1.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.1.8].
- drupal/core-recommended 10.1.8 requires psr/log ~3.0.0 -> found psr/log[3.0.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

Problem 2
- drupal/core[10.0.x-dev, ..., 10.2.x-dev] require psr/log ^3.0 -> found psr/log[dev-master, 3.0.0, 3.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

- drupal/core[10.2.0-alpha1, ..., 10.4.x-dev] require symfony/console ^6.4 -> found symfony/console[v6.4.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.0.0-alpha2] require symfony/console ^5.4 -> found symfony/console[v5.4.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha3, ..., 10.0.0-alpha5] require symfony/console ^6.0 -> found symfony/console[v6.0.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha6, ..., 10.0.0-beta2] require symfony/console ^6.1 -> found symfony/console[v6.1.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- drupal/core 10.0.0-rc1 requires symfony/console ^6.2@beta -> found symfony/console[v6.2.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- drupal/core[10.0.0-rc2, ..., 10.1.0-alpha1] require symfony/console ^6.2 -> found symfony/console[v6.2.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- drupal/core[10.1.0-beta1, ..., 10.1.8] require symfony/console ^6.3 -> found symfony/console[v6.3.0-BETA1, ..., 6.4.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- drupal/sparkpost 3.0.0-alpha1 requires drupal/core ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.4.x-dev].
- Root composer.json requires drupal/sparkpost ^3.0@alpha -> satisfiable by drupal/sparkpost[3.0.0-alpha1].

